# How do you make macOS notifications stay open and immediately show action buttons?

Tags: macos, notifications

When creating macOS notifications based on `UNNotificationRequest` and `UNNotificationCategory`, it is possible to make notifications that appear briefly and with an action button that is invisible until you hover the notification.

However, I have seen many notifications that stay open and with an action button immediately visible (ie, without having to hover the notification to see the button) - for instance the system update available notification and the MS Office Update notifications. I have not been able to tweak the notification objects to make this possible (hoped that the `.destructive` option would make a difference).

Is it a different kind of notifications? Or is it possible to tweak the `UNNotificationRequest` based ones? Or is it not possible at all for "regular" (non-system) applications?

Comment: I believe this is up to the user. In System Preferences > Notifications, they have to select your app and set the alert style to "Alerts" rather than "Banners".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the notification style "Alerts" as suggested by Ken Thomases is what I was looking for. It is supposedly possible to set this as default in your app's `Info.plist` through the key `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle` ([apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW19)):

> NSUserNotificationAlertStyle (String - macOS) specifies the
>   notification style the app should use. The default value, banner, is
>   recommended; most apps should not need to use the alert style.

However, this does not seem to work as of 2020 - and indeed there are several reports about this not working online.

Also, several posts online that this is not supposed to be possible to do from within the app in the first place. So I give up and wonder why that Microsoft Office Updater is able to present using alert style - I am 100% certain I have never changed its presentation style in Notification settings.